# Advantage/Disadvantage to + -ing form

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

Reading an essay I found the following sentence:

> On the other hand, there are definitely **disadvantages to being** at home while your parents are away.

Does *to* work as a combination with *disadvantage*?

Comment: Do you want to know if "disadvantages to being" is correct? If so, yes it is. It also works with other verbs, for example: There are disadvantages to running away.

Comment: @Silenus I know it's correct. It's an essay taken from my book. But I'm wondering if *desadvantage to* is always a combination. (So in that case *to* is a preposition.)

Comment: No, you can also say: "There are disadvantages being a minority" [**no preposition**]; "There are disadvantages **for** minorities"; "There are disadvantages **that come with** being a minority," etc.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on use and context, the preposition "of" sometimes fits better: "There are disadvantages to being born poor" v. "The disadvantages of being born poor are..."

When you use "to" a person is implied. "There are disadvantages to [a person]...". However, if you choose to make explicit reference to the person, then  the prepositions needed are "to" and "in": "The disadvantages to the aboriginals in having inadequate weapons...."